# Не могу запустить pulseaudio в WSL 2

Tags: wsl2, pulseaudio

Пытался похимичить с pulseaudio для того, чтобы заставить его видеть виртуальные аудио-устройства. В какой-то момент перестал запускаться по команде **pulseaudio --start**. Пробовал его переустанавливать и вычищать все его папки - не помогло. Ошибка: N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at unix:/mnt/wslg/PulseServer, refusing to start/autospawn.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, что ошибка, с которой вы столкнулись, связана с тем, что PulseAudio пытается использовать предыдущую конфигурацию сервера, которая не существует или повреждена. Есть несколько шагов, которые можно предпринять, чтобы попытаться решить эту проблему.

Попробуйте удалить все папки и файлы, связанные с PulseAudio, чтобы начать с чистого листа. Вы можете найти эти файлы в вашей домашней директории, а также в системных папках, где установлен PulseAudio.

Затем попробуйте переустановить PulseAudio, чтобы обеспечить настройку с нуля.

После этого попробуйте запустить PulseAudio снова. Если вы все еще видите ошибку, попробуйте создать новый сервер PulseAudio с помощью команды:

```
pulseaudio --start --exit-idle-time=-1
```

Такая команда позволяет запустить PulseAudio и предотвращает его выход в режим ожидания.

Если ничего из вышеперечисленного не помогло, попробуйте обратиться к сообществу WSL или форумам, где пользователи WSL 2 обсуждают проблемы и решения.